# In Processing, using serial port, why is .equals not returning true?

Tags: processing, arduino-uno

I am using Processing to display data coming into the serial port.
I have simple string values coming into the serial port.

I have cut down all my code to this basic point of failure and I cannot understand why it fails. **The if statement never evaluates to true.** (I'm not trying to compare strings with = or == )

Please help if you know why this is happening :) I'd really appreciate an answer.

Ugh Alright then, since I don't have a reputation of 10, I won't post the helpful screenshot.
Here is the code that fails:

```
    enter code here
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

String val;  //Data recieved from the serial port

void setup() {
  size(400,300);

  String portName = Serial.list()[2]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port //1 or 2  for USB on the Mac
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}



void serialEvent (Serial myPort){
 val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
 print(val);
  if(val != null){   
    if(val.equals("New sample set")){
      print("yes\n");
    } else {
      print("not equal\n");
    }

  }
}


void draw() {
  //The serialEvent controls the display
}
```

I have tried taking out the spaces and making it only one letter, but this did not help. I have tried using if(val.equals("New sample set")==true) but that didn't help either.

Comment: In the screenshot that I don't have permission to add, you can see a clue: When I print val in the console, it prints a new line, so I'm guessing the problem is because val actually contains a new line character. I have tried adding a \n  but still no luck. I have also tried using trim() to get rid of any unwanted characters but this did not work either.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I don't believe `trim()` actually removes `\n` characters from strings.

Answer (score 3):

Alrighty, it only took a few hours but I have answered my own question :)

**Yes, comparing strings must be done with .equals()**
and
**Yes, they must be trimmed so that all line feed characters are eliminated.**

**I was using trim incorrectly.
Simply saying myString.trim(); will not do.
this returns a string, so it needs to be placed somewhere; here's how:
myString=myString.trim();**

I know, kind of obvious to the experienced coder, but I just couldn't see it. And I thought bufferUntil('\n') would only buffer the stuff before the \n... I guess not.
Hope the hours I spent in this silly little "boggle" can help someone else!
:)
Happy coding!!!

Successful processing code below:

```js
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

String val;  //Data recieved from the serial port

void setup() {
  size(400,300);
  
  String portName = Serial.list()[2]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port //1 or 2  for USB on the Mac
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}


void serialEvent (Serial myPort){
 val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
 print("After reading serial, val is "+val+".\n");
 val=val.trim();
 print("After trimming, val is "+val+".\n");
  if(val != null){   
     print("After comparing to null, val is "+val+".\n");
    if("N".equals(val)){
      print("yes\n");
    } else {
      print(val+" is not equal to \"N\".\n");
    }

  }

}


void draw() {
  //The serialEvent controls the display
}
```